# stripping index values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with several dozen columns and am sorting two columns in question by Max value and storing the result in a variable to print it later to a report.  How do I only return the Two columns so that they are on the same as my string "Max".  Below is the method I am using which returns the ID # in my variable also.

```
#Create DF     
prim1 = mru[['Time', 'Motion:MRU']]
# Sort     
prim1 = prim1.sort(['Motion:MRU'], ascending=True)
primmin = prim1['Motion:MRU'].min()
print 'Max: ', prim1[:1]
```

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to do exactly here? it sounds like all you are asking is how to print 2 values? Can you post what your desired output should look like based on representative data because at the moment you already have a two column df in `prim1` so I don't understand your problem?

Comment: My desired output is something like this `Max: 23:00:01 0.52` The print is just to check the formatting of the variable I am going to have it printed to a report when I am done. Right Now it is preserving the Header in the variable and printing this `1475 Max: 23:00:01 0.52`

Comment: So you want `print 'Max: ', prim1[:1].values[0]`?

Comment: Exactly thanks....can you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you see printed will be a pandas Series in the form of :

```
<index> <value>
```

If you want just the value then you access the numpy array data attribute by doing this:

```
print 'Max: ', prim1[:1].values[0]
```

This will return a numpy array with a single element and then to access the scalar value you subscript the single value using `[0]`